# Spring mvc category tree

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have category tree.My category has n number subcategories.How do list recursion category on jsp?

```
List<Category> categories = categoryService.findAll();
modelMap.put("categories",categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSTL, try something like this:

**Simple List of Items**

```
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
   ${category.id} -> ${category.name}
</c:forEach>
```

**Nested List of Items**

If you have nested categories, try something like the following custom tag.

```
public class CategoryDisplayTag extends TagSupport
{
   public int doStartTag() throws JspException
   {
      Category rootCategory = new Category();

      printEachCategory(rootCategory);

      return SKIP_BODY;
   }

   private void printEachCategory(Category category)
   {
      JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();

      try
      {
         out.write("Category: " + category.getName());

         for (Category c : category.getCategories())
         {
            out.write("Sub-category: " + c.getName());
            printEachCategory(c);
         }
      }
      catch (IOException e1)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException(e1);
      }

   }  
}
```

Comment: My problem: Categories has endless tree.

Comment: Are you stating each Category has a Category, too?

Comment: Yes Category has a Category,

Comment: MainCategory
==>SubCategory1=>SubCategory1.1=>SubCategory1.1.1==>SubCategory2

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of how you need this displayed, but I would consider a JSTL custom tag.  Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31614/JSP-JSTL-Custom-Tag-Library where you could use a tag to recursively iterate over your items.